# Some smashy applications of Grönwall's lemma

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I'm having a difficult time finding smashy applications of Grönwall's inequality on the web. It did become important in a proof of the local existence of solutions to the Euler equation, but instead of just memorising it, I want to learn it in context. (I do know that it is sometimes used to develop basic ODE theory such as Picard--Lindelöf, but I prefer using elementary inequalities to do so.)

I wonder if anyone has some references regarding "Grönwallology".

I'd also be grateful for any exercises, or general explanations of the "yoga" of the Grönwall inequality, preferably with reference to the different types of Grönwall inequalities.

Comment: I think that Gronwall is somewhat elementary, but that probably depends on taste. Gronwall you can use to prove some continuation about ODE results. But where it is really strong is when you want to prove stability results for PDEs, i.e. are there estimates of the form $\lVert q \rVert \leq C \lVert q_0 \rVert$ for time dependent PDEs.

Comment: Don't be extreme with "yoga" or "Grönwallology". There are some books on the subject. Here is one of them https://rgmia.org/papers/monographs/standard.pdf

Comment: @BlackMild Sorry, I'm going to be more mild in the future.